# How to open an external file while a FORTRAN program is running

Tags: file-io, fortran

I have a FORTRAN code which performs a numerical integration. All the computed data are written in an external file (data.out). Here is a simple sketch of the code

```
OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='data.out')
DO i=1,n

........

WRITE(10,'(7(E22.16,1x))')a,b,c,d,e,f,g

........

ENDDO
CLOSE(10)
```

The program keeps running for long time (about 1.5 h) until the numerical integration is finished. During the execution I would like to see the results in the .out file. However, when I try to open the .out file while the .exe is running I get the following message: 
"The document data.out is used by another application and cannot be accessed." So, is there a way to open the .out file during the execution? It is important for me to observe the output values (they are not only seven as in the above example) so, it is not convenient to send them in screen output (is reduces significantly the speed of the code). 
Many thanks in advance.

---

*** EDIT ***

---

This is another scenario quite similar to the above mentioned case. Here, the integration routine reads the initial conditions from an input file and writes the outputs to another external file. Below I present the corresponding skeleton of the code

```
     OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='input.par',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
 2   READ(10,*,END=1) x_0,y_0

 !   INTEGRATION LOOP
     DO i=1,n
     ........
     ENDDO

     OPEN(UNIT=12,FILE='data.out')
     WRITE(12,'(7(E22.16,1x))')a,b,c,d,e,f,g

     GOTO 2

 1   CLOSE(10)
     CLOSE(12)
```

So, the routine opens UNIT 10 reads the initial conditions, performs the integration and at the end of the integration it writes the outputs to UNIT 12. Then, it takes another set of initial conditions and repeat the same procedure until it there is no more initial conditions in UNIT 10. Again, I want to be able to open and monitor UNIT 12. I tried your approach but it does not work properly at this case. I can open UNIT 12 any time I want but the routine does not write all the outputs there. In fact, it writes only the outputs of the last set of initial conditions. Any ideas? I strongly believe that a minor modification to your approach could do the job.

Comment: Which operating system?   Have you tried the `tail` command?

Comment: obviously windows.  The best answer to this question is "install linux"..

Comment: Looked into this a bit  - windows does permit multiple processes acesing a file, but you need to specify fileshare mode when you open the file.  You might try reading your compiler documentation to see if there is a hook to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to printing out the result to the screen, you could just close your file after each write operation and reopen it in the next integration cycle to *append* the new data to it.

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer :: ii

  ! Create emtpy file
  open(10, file='data.out', status='REPLACE', action='WRITE')
  close(10)

  do ii = 1, 100
    !...
    ! Reopen file, append new information and close it again.
    open(10, file='data.out', status='OLD', action='WRITE', position='APPEND')
    write(10,'(7(E23.16,1x))') 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0
    close(10)
  end do

end program test
```

EDIT: THe main idea is, that before you start any kind of looping, you create an empty file by the first open statement:

```
  open(10, file='data.out', status='REPLACE', action='WRITE')
  close(10)
```

Then, inside the loop you just *append* to that file, to make sure you do not replace content already being there:

```
open(10, file='data.out', status='OLD', action='WRITE', position='APPEND')
write(10,'(7(E23.16,1x))') 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0
close(10)
```

Please note the differences in the arguments passed to the `open` statement.

Comment: It might be more efficient to close and then reopen the file after some number of write operations, rather than after each write operation.  You might want to experiment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It really works. However, I have another scenario (see my EDIT) in which your approach does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You should *append* to the file, instead of *replacing* its content. I just updated my post to make the idea more clear. If you do not specify `position` and `status` accordingly (or you do not specify them at all), your file will be recreated with empty content at each `open` statement.

Comment: Beware, now if you open that file to look at it and happen to still have it open when your fortran gets around to reopening it you may throw an error in the fortran.  You should add code to handle that event gracefully..

Answer (score 0):

The logical way to do this would be to echo the output to the terminal. By default, this is unit 6. So I would change your output to:

```
WRITE(6,'(7(E22.16,1x))')a,b,c,d,e,f,g
WRITE(10,'(7(E22.16,1x))')a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Try it and see. It may even work.

Comment: An io-unit of * nominates the terminal (or OUTPUT_UNIT from the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV intrinsic module if you actually want an integer value).  Whether 6 is or is not connected to the terminal depends on the compiler (I have at least one compiler that does not pre-connect 6).  It is a retrograde step to introduce compiler dependencies in a program when the portable option is trivially different.

Comment: You are probably right, Ian. It is a long time since I used FORTRAN.